# reset Dymola flags to default value from mos script

Tags: scripting, dymola

Is there a command to reset all Dymola flags to their default value from a .mos script?
The GUI has a button to do it, I basically need a mos command that does the same as the "Reset All Flags" button at the bottom left:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJJ8h.png]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This command should reset all flags to default:

```
DymolaCommands.System.clearFlags()
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks.